# Neo4j CREATE for 150M nodes and 100M edges losing connection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running some scalability testing for my graph structure (shown below) and am using the neo4j browser interface to create and query the graph. While running the following command works for 500,000 nodes, graphs bigger than 2M, not only maximize CPU usage but also lose connection to the local server (assuming its a time out because it takes long?).

```
FOREACH (r IN range(1,50000000) | CREATE (:entity {id:r})-[:IN_ASSOCIATION]->(iassoc:association{id:r})<-[:IN_ASSOCIATION]-(:entity{id:r+50000000}), (iassoc)-[:IN_DOC]->(:doc{id:r}))
```

Are there better alternative to generate and populate neo4j with a large number of nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and try using the procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "WITH range(1, 50000000) AS rs UNWIND rs AS r RETURN r",
    "CREATE (:entity {id:r})-[:IN_ASSOCIATION]->(iassoc:association{id:r})<-[:IN_ASSOCIATION]-(:entity{id:r+50000000}), (iassoc)-[:IN_DOC]->(:doc{id:r})",
{batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

The docs about this procedure says:

> With `apoc.periodic.iterate` you provide 2 statements, the first outer
>   statement is providing a stream of values to be processed. The second,
>   inner statement processes one element at a time (...).

So, the first statement is returning `r` from 1 to 50000000. The second statement is receiving `r` as parameter and creating the nodes and relationships as desired.

*Note: remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [version compatibility matrix.](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix)*

*Note (2): the plugins folder needs to be in the database folder rather than the installation folder (unless the config file is manually changed to direct to the installation folder).*

Comment: Thanks! Just to add a quick note, in addition to the docs: the plugins folder needs to be in the database folder rather than the installation folder (unless the config file is manually changed to direct to the installation folder). Also, if anyone else is building something similar, insertion takes a very long time.